# Change the main menu with classes from a sub-page

Tags: php, css

On a WordPress site, there are some Twitter posts on a page specifically for Twitter and need to change the appearance of the menu whether or not if there are some "Tweets" there. Twitter is used for notifications about downtime, system failures, etc. and a symbol should flash on the menu on every page if there are any tweets on the specific page, to indicate important notices.

I have uploaded a warning symbol that is blinking by CSS and I'm thinking of hiding it when there are no twitter-message(s) or making it visible when there are some. Tweets get deleted when the problem is solved so I'm thinking of using a "no tweet"-class as a trigger, which is `.timeline-EmptyMessage` that shows up from the Twitter-script when all tweets are deleted.

I'm currently looking into using the function `if (class_exists('timeline-EmptyMessage')) {.symbol-class: visibility: hidden}` within functions.php, but I probably need to point it to what page the class may exist on?

The twitter integration script is:

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="no" data-width="600" data-height="500" data-theme="light" href="URL">Tweet by</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: `class_exists` checks if a PHP class exists, it has absolutely nothing to do with CSS classes.

Comment: _“which is `.timeline-EmptyMessage` that shows up from the Twitter-script”_ - if you are referring to anything their client-side JavaScript sets anywhere … then you can not get that using server-side code in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I were thinking about only using .timeline-EmptyMessage that Twitter generates on the site as a trigger, not to modify anything. I just need to bind something in the menu to "any tweet or no tweet".

Comment: Maybe it is better to use jQuery within a PHP-function to hook on the menu.

Comment: _“that Twitter generates on the site”_ - it does that only on the client side, so there is nothing you could access directly via PHP here in the first place. And it only happens, when the page is actually opened by the site visitor.

Comment: _“Maybe it is better to use jQuery within a PHP-function to hook on the menu”_ - still, someone would have to have the page the twitter widget is embedded on opened in their browser to begin with.